# Dynamic list navigation linking abnormally

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, css, dom-manipulation

I created a dynamic horizontal navigation menu that gets its data from SharePoint lists.  It renders and works great but I am dealing with a situation that is very abnormal.  The items in the navigation are all links but link that's in the DOM and the link that I see when I hover over them are different. When I click the item, it always leads me to a broken page.  See below for an example.
[image]

Someone please explain why this is happening and how to fix.  Here's the code:

```
var cacheNavData = [];
var cacheSubNavData = [];
var cacheMegaMenuData = [];
var cacheCategoryMenuData = [];

$(document).ready(function(){
    getData("Training Navigation").done(function(data1){
        cacheNavData = data1.d.results;
            console.log(cacheNavData);        
        getData("Sub Navigation").done(function(data2){
            cacheSubNavData = data2.d.results;
            console.log(cacheSubNavData);
            getData("Mega Menu Category").done(function(data3){
                cacheMegaMenuData = data3.d.results;
                getData("category menu").done(function(data4){
                    cacheCategoryMenuData = data4.d.results;
                    //alert(cacheCategoryMenuData)
                    createNavigation(cacheNavData);
                });
            });
        });
    });
})
function getData(lName){
    var endPointUrl=_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
    if (lName != "Sub Navigation") {    
        endPointUrl+= "/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('" + lName + "')/items";
    }else {
        endPointUrl+="/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('" + lName + "')/items?$select=parentNav/URL, parentNav/URLNAME,subLink&$expand=parentNav";
    }
    
    return $.ajax({
        url: endPointUrl,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept":"application/json;odata=verbose"
        }
    }); 
}
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}

function createNavigation(navData) {
    var topNav = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    for (var x = 0; x < navData.length; x++) {
        if (navData[x].dropDown === "no") {
            var aLink = _createEl("a");
            var aTextNode = document.createTextNode(navData[x].URLNAME);
            aLink.href = navData[x].URL;
            aLink.appendChild(aTextNode);
            topNav.appendChild(aLink);
        } else if (navData[x].dropDown === "yes") {
            var buildSubNavigation;
            buildSubNavigation = buildSubNavBar(navData[x]);
            topNav.appendChild(buildSubNavigation);
        } else {
            //build megamenu
            var buildSubNavigation;
            buildDirectorateNav = buildDirectorateMegaMenu(navData[x]);
        }
    }
}

function buildDirectorateMegaMenu(navDataID) {
    var buildNav;
    var topNav = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    buildNav = buildSubNavBar(navDataID, "training");  //Build mega menu and attach in buildSubNavBar()
    topNav.appendChild(buildNav);
}

function buildSubNavBar(subNavID, isDirectorate) {
    //create div and add dropdown class
    var ddDiv = _createEl("div");
    if(isDirectorate === "training"){
        ddDiv.classList.add("Mdropdown");
    }else{
        ddDiv.classList.add("dropdown");
    }
    //create button and add text
    var btn = _createEl("button");
    if(isDirectorate === "training"){
        btn.classList.add("Mdropbtn");
    }else{
        btn.classList.add("dropbtn");
    }
    var btnText = document.createTextNode(subNavID.URLNAME);
    
    var aLink = _createEl("a");
    var aTextNode = document.createTextNode(btnText.data);
    aLink.href = subNavID.URL;
    aLink.appendChild(aTextNode);
    
    //append the text to the button
    btn.appendChild(aLink);

    //create i tag and add "fa fa-caret-down" classes
    var itag = _createEl("i");
    itag.classList.add("fa");
    itag.classList.add("fa-caret-down");
    btn.appendChild(itag);
    ddDiv.appendChild(btn);

    var ddContent = _createEl("div");
    ddContent.classList.add("dropdown-content");
    for (var i = 0; i < cacheSubNavData.length; i++) {
        if (cacheSubNavData[i].parentNav.URLNAME=== subNavID.URLNAME  && cacheSubNavData[i].parentNav.URLNAME !== "Training") {
            var li = _createEl("li");
            var a = _createEl("a");
            var aTextNode = document.createTextNode(cacheSubNavData[i].subLink.Description);

            a.href = cacheSubNavData[i].subLink.Url;
            a.appendChild(aTextNode);
            ddContent.appendChild(a);  
        }
    }

    if(isDirectorate === "training"){
        //alert("I ");
        //create div and add dropdown class
        var megaDivDropDown = _createEl("div");
        megaDivDropDown.classList.add("dropdown");

        var megaBtn = _createEl("button");
        megaBtn.classList.add("dropbtn");

        megaDivDropDown.appendChild(megaBtn);
        var megaI = _createEl("i");
        megaI.classList.add("fa");
        megaI.classList.add("fa-caret-down");

        megaBtn.appendChild(megaI);

        var megaDDivContent = _createEl("div");
        megaDDivContent.classList.add("Mdropdown-content");

        var headerDiv = _createEl("div");
        headerDiv.classList.add("Mheader");

        var megaH2 = _createEl("h2");
        var h2Text = document.createTextNode("Team Sites");

        megaH2.appendChild(h2Text);
        headerDiv.appendChild(megaH2);
        megaDDivContent.appendChild(headerDiv);

        var megaDDivRow = _createEl("div");
        megaDDivRow.classList.add("Mrow");

        //Loop through categories & sub-categories items
        for (var i = 0; i < cacheMegaMenuData.length; i++) {
            var megaDivCol = _createEl("div");
            megaDivCol.classList.add("Mcolumn");
            var colHr = _createEl("h3");
            var colHrText = document.createTextNode(cacheMegaMenuData[i].category);
            colHr.appendChild(colHrText);
            megaDivCol.appendChild(colHr);
            for (var x = 0; x < cacheCategoryMenuData.length; x++) {
                if (cacheMegaMenuData[i].category === cacheCategoryMenuData[x].category) {
                    var colAnchor = _createEl("a");
                    colAnchor.href = cacheCategoryMenuData[x].menuUrl;
                    var menuColText = document.createTextNode(cacheCategoryMenuData[x].menuItem);
                    colAnchor.appendChild(menuColText);

                    megaDivCol.appendChild(colAnchor);
                    megaDDivRow.appendChild(megaDivCol);
                    megaDDivContent.appendChild(megaDDivRow);
                    ddDiv.appendChild(megaDDivContent);
                }
            }
            //create the other stuff
            //console.log(megaDivCol)
            console.log("megaDdivRow:");
            console.log(ddDiv);
        }
    }
    ddDiv.appendChild(ddContent);
    return ddDiv;
}    
function _createEl(el) {
    return document.createElement(el);
}
```

I created a [mock-up](https://codepen.io/isogunro/pen/oNxzxYK?editors=0010), but it really does behave the same way because it come from an array of objects.

I hope someone can help me with this.  It's mind boggling and I've been dealing with this for **DAYS**.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint,if you want to visit external website,you need to add "http://" or "https://" to the url,otherwise it will find the page in SharePoint.

**Demo:**

Site url:`https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/dev`
Subsite url:`https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/subsite`

url in a tag:`/sites/dev/subsite`

Comment: What about for internal links? such as to different subsites?

Comment: Check the update.

Comment: I'll give that a try

Comment: I gave it a try.  It works great in one environment but doesn't in another environment. It always redirects to whatever page I'm currently on.

Comment: You can also use the full sunsite url directly.

Comment: That's what I initially did but same problem.  It's just very strange

Comment: Share me the urls.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share the urls b/c it's private but I used the same exact code on my personal site and it doesn't do that.  It is very abnormal

Comment: The weird thing is that it only happens to those items that have a drop down.  In the image above, it doesn't happen to Home or Site B.  Same thing in production environment.

Comment: Can you access the subsite directly?
Perhaps there are some security policies that prevent access. You can ask the administrator if there are any security policies in this area.And you can also observe the requested URL through the developer tools.

Comment: Yes, I can access them directly

Comment: Doesn’t the external website access?

Comment: no it does not.